# Proving that a function is one-to-one

Tags: functions

I want to prove that this function is one-to-one.

$$f:(5,\infty)\to \mathbb R \text{ with }  f(x)=10x-x^2.$$

Also, I want to prove that this function is not one-to-one.
$$f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R \text{ with }f(x)=x^2-3x.$$

Answer (score 2):

for  $f(x)=10x-x^2$ we have. $f'(x)=10-2x=0$ then for $(5,\infty)$ it is decreasing function thus it is one to one.

$f(x)=x^2-3x$  isnot one to one since $f(0)=f(3)=0$

Comment: I want a general demonstration for the second function

Comment: dear if  a function be one to one then if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1 =x_2$, when you want show that $f$ isnot one to one, it is enough to find $x_1 \neq x_2$ that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ . here $0 \neq 3$ but $f(0)=f(3)$

Comment: You can also calculate $f'(x)=2x-3$. This has a zero for $x=3/2$. Form this you can conclude that $f'(x)$ changes sign and the function is not strictly monotonous. Hence, it is not one-to-one (injective)

Comment: @Razieh Noori So, for other functions, do I need to try combinations of two numbers or what?

Comment: oh i got what you want. it depends on your function.  some times it is hard to reach result by  using for example $x_{1}^{2}-3x_1=x_{2}^{2}-3x_2$ and show that it willnot give $x_1=x_2$. it wil be easy for a function like $y=\vert x\vert.

Comment: @MJay1985 What it is f' ?

Comment: $\dfrac{df}{dx}=f'$

Comment: @Bogdan15 see this link http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/115/applications/increaseDecrease.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show that the first function is not one-to-one (without using calculus):

To show that $f:(5, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by the formula $f(x) = 10 x - x^2$ is one-to-one you have to show that for any $x, y \in (5, \infty)$, if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x = y$. So let $x, y \in (5, \infty)$ be arbitrary and assume that $f(x) = f(y)$. Then,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
10 x - x^2 &=& 10 y - y^2 \\
\implies 10(x - y) &=& x^2 - y^2 \\
\implies 10(x - y) &=& (x + y)(x - y)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now suppose, for contradiction, that $x \neq y$. Then because $x > 5$ and $y > 5$, $x + y > 10$. Hence $10(x - y) \neq (x + y)(x - y)$. But this is impossible since we have already shown that $10(x - y) = (x + y)(x - y)$. Hence $x = y$. As $x$, $y$ were arbitrary it follows that $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: I guess that for every function I can apply that